# is there a small music video player, fixed on desktop to play music videos while doing other things?

Tags: video-player, music-player, media

Is there a way to play music videos in a small window on top of everything. Basically I have some mpeg music videos and would like to play them while I am browsing, but I'd like to pin it to a part of the desktop that I choose.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take your video player, right-click the titlebar, and check "Always on Visible Workspace".  It wouldn't be pinned to the desktop per se, but you could always see it if you resized your windows to make room.

If want to see videos while browsing, you could drag your player of choice to the bottom-right and click "Always on top".  Then you can maximize your web browser and continue as normal.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a usefull screenlet for this action may be there is a tool for it but there isn't any widget or screenlet

Comment: Because you are just ruling out a possibility, perhaps this doesn't belong as a question?